# How do I fix animateWithDuration from stopping CGRectIntersectsRect when they meet?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an image that animates (goes up the screen then back down the screen) but the problem I am having is when the `animateWithDuration` meets the `CGRectIntersectsRect` then the `CGRectIntersectsRect` gets fired. There was no collusion between the two images. I want the image thats getting animated to collide with `CGRectIntersectsRect`. Then the `CGRectIntersectsRect` gets fired. In other words the problem I am having is the image can be up above the `CGRectIntersectsRect` image and still the `CGRectIntersectsRect` would get fired. There was no collusion between the two images. And I want to fix this so when the two images collide the 
`CGRectIntersectsRect` code gets fired instead when they meet on the y-xis.

Heres my code:

```
 NSTimeInterval durationUp = 0.5;
[UIView animateWithDuration:durationUp delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     CGRect f = jumperguy.frame;
                     f.origin.y -= 150;
                     jumperguy.frame = f;



                 }
                 completion:nil];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5  delay:durationUp
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                 animations:^{
                     CGRect f = jumperguy.frame;
                     f.origin.y += 150;
                     jumperguy.frame = f;



                 }
                 completion:nil];
```

and

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(jumperguy.frame, hurdle2.frame)) {

    [movement invalidate];

    l.hidden = NO;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do won't work. You'll need a completely different approach.

When you do use Core Animation or UIView animation, the object moves to it's final location instantly. It's just the underlying "presentation layer" that animates.

In order to do what you're trying to do you would need a timer to trigger checking the animation on each frame. You probably want to use CADisplayLink for your timer, because it's fast and frame-accurate, unlike NSTimer. Then, in the timer code, you have to check the presentation layer of the layer that's being animated.

UIView animation usually animates the layer of the view that is being animated, so you may be able to check your view's layer's presentation layers, with code like this:

CGRectIntersectsRect(jumperguy.layer.presentationLayer.frame, hurdle2.layer.presentationLayer.frame)

I haven't tried to do exactly what you want to do, so I'm not positive it will work, but it should.

Comment: I got a Property 'frame' not found on object of type 'id' error. @Duncan C

Comment: Ok, so see if you can figure out how to solve it. Hint: One of the properties in the expression is of type id, when it should be of type CALayer. You'll need to cast it to the correct type.